# Выбор элементов в jQuery

Tags: jquery

Вот пример:

```
<ul>
    <li class="qwerty" name="John">
        <div class="ururu">
            <div class="ololo"><div class="tratata"></div></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="qwerty" name="John">
        <div class="ururu">
            <div class="ololo"><div class="tratata"></div></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="qwerty" name="John">
        <div class="ururu">
            <div class="ololo"><div class="tratata"></div>/div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="qwerty" name="John">
        <div class="ururu">
            <div class="ololo"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="qwerty" name="John">
        <div class="ururu">
            <div class="ololo"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="qwerty" name="John">
        <div class="ururu">
            <div class="ololo"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="qwerty" name="John">
        <div class="ururu">
            <div class="ololo"><div class="tratata"></div></div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Не могу придумать как выбрать только те ли у которых нет среди дочерних div'а .tratata...как выбрать те у которых он есть я понял, а вот как те у которых наоборот его нет, не могу додумать

Comment: А какие именно элементы вы пытаетесь выбрать? `li`?

Comment: да, допустим если нет дочернего div'а tratata поменять name на Bruce

Comment: см. мой ответ ниже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В jQuery есть селектор `:not` который позволяет накладывать отрицательные условия при выборе элементов. В вашем случае, можно использовать его комбинацию с селектором `:has`, например так:

```
$('li:not(:has(.tratata))').attr('name', 'Bruce');
```

Подробнее о селекторе `:not`: https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Подробнее о селекторе `:has`: https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/